# Regression models with log, standardized and in percentages variables

Tags: regression, interpretation

I am trying to interpret regression results. 
According to some previous threads, when using log of independent variable (X), it means that 1% increase in X would lead to a β/100 increase/decrease in the dependent variable (Y).

What would be the interpretation if the Y is in percentages? For example, the coefficient is 5, so a 1% change in X would lead to 5% or 0.05% in Y?
In addition, two common options prevailing in research – what would be the interpretation?

1. X is standardized (mean=0, std=1) and the Y is in percentages.
2. Both X and Y are in percentages.

Any help would be appreciated.